# is there something like a jira uml diagram?

Tags: jira

i'm very new to jira and the abilities of customizing and setting up a project/role/group and so on are very confusing to me.

do you know if there is something like an overview how everything acts together, like an UML diagram?

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest to go to the admin workflow editor and have a look at those used in your projects (or the default workflow at first) in the graphical representation. There you can look at the transitions between the status and check their details.

You will notice conditions, validators and post-functions, if you want that level of detail you can check those in the standard workflow and see which fields are manipulated and/or checked.

This would be the closest to an UML diagram I could think of.

Other than that I suggest to simply create a test project, create test issues and use those like your company/department works. It will all fall together very quickly, especially if you do that together with people from all roles involved.